# How to specify which TCP protocol (HTTP,FTP,...) Java sockets use?

Tags: java, sockets

How do Java sockets understand that they must use FTP or HTTP or other TCP/IP protocols? Is there any specific socket method for any protocol?

Comment: If by "socket" you mean an instance of java.net.Socket, they aren't associated with any particular protocol. Sockets of this form handle TCP/IP data streams. If you want to handle FTP or HTTP, you will either need to build the logic on top of Socket, or use one of the built in URL-handling classes, typically by instantiating a java.net.URL with the appropriate URL. Or you could use some library that provides the additional protocol-specific logic, e.g., Apache HttpClient for HTTP

Comment: What [tag:websocket] has to do with this question is another mystery.

Answer (score 0):

> How Java sockets understand that they must use FTP or HTTP or other TCP/IP protocols?

They don't. They use the TCP protocol. Application protocols such as FTP or HTTP are implemented *over* sockets, by the *application,* usually via a protocol-specific library.

> Is there any specific socket method for any protocol?

I've tried but I cannot ascribe any cogent meaning to this question.